# Meaning of "warm threshold"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> But there is something that I must say to my people, who stand on the **warm threshold** which leads into the palace of justice: In the process of gaining our rightful place, we must not be guilty of wrongful deeds. Let us not seek to satisfy our thirst for freedom by drinking from the cup of bitterness and hatred. We must forever conduct our struggle on the high plane of dignity and discipline. We must not allow our creative protest to degenerate into physical violence. Again and again, we must rise to the majestic heights of meeting physical force with soul force. [Source](https://www.americanrhetoric.com/speeches/mlkihaveadream.htm)

What does "warm threshold" mean in this paragraph? I have searched up the meanings of threshold and they do not seem to fit this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Threshold" seems to be in the normal sense, except that it's a metaphorical palace with a metaphorical threshold. Metaphorically, a "threshold" means the point of entry or exit. Here, it looks like it's about people who are about to get access to justice.

"Warm" is probably in the poetic sense, meaning something like "welcoming", "comfortable", "safe" and so on.

It's something like this from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warm):

> **2 :** comfortably established : SECURE